# Maximum point cloud thinning

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, lidar

My goal is to implement a python function to thin a lidar point cloud by returning only points with the highest `z` values inside each non-overlapping grid cell.

Only one point is returned per grid cell.

I have written the following function in python but it is taking much longer (about 10 slower) to process samples files compared to a similar implementation in MATLAB.

Is there anything in the function I could change to speed it up?

In the function, data is a Nx3 array and csize is the size of the non-overlapping grid cells.

```
def pcthin(data, csize):
 md = data
 xx = np.arange(np.min(md[:,0]), csize*(np.ceil(max(md[:,0]))/csize), csize)
 yy = np.arange(np.min(md[:,1]), csize*(np.ceil(max(md[:,1]))/csize), csize)
 X,Y = np.meshgrid(xx,yy, sparse=False, indexing='xy')

 thindata = np.zeros_like(data)
 k = 0
 xf = X.flatten()
 yf = Y.flatten()
 for x,y in zip(xf,yf):
    tf1 = np.logical_and(md[:,0] > x, md[:,0] <= x + csize)
    tf2 = np.logical_and(md[:,1] > y, md[:,1] <= y + csize)
    tf = np.logical_and(tf1,tf2)
    if any(tf):
        dtx = md[tf,:]
        ix = np.argmax(dtx[:,2])
        thindata[k,:] = dtx[ix,:]

        k = k + 1

return thindata[0:k+1,:]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update Answer about the code**

The thing is that naive "for" loops are slow in Python, and your code has a big for loop. To get the maximum speed for Python you should either try to ["vectorize" your code](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html) or use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) and try to re-write your code with for loops like you were writing C++.

---

**Old answer**

So If I understand your question correctly, this is how you could get it done using https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud

---

Load an example point cloud:

```
from pyntcloud import PyntCloud
cloud = PyntCloud.from_file("tests/data/sphere.ply")
```

Which looks like this:

[image: sphere]

---

Then you have to build a grid of non-overlapping cells (called voxelgrid in pyntcloud).

Here `size_x` and `size_y` is how you specify the size of the cell along each axis.

```
voxelgrid_id = cloud.add_structure("voxelgrid", size_x=10, size_y=10)
```

The voxelgrid looks like this:

[image: voxelgrid]

---

And finally you can get a new point cloud by selecting the highest point of each cell:

```
thinned_cloud = cloud.get_sample(
    "voxelgrid_highest",
    voxelgrid_id=voxelgrid_id,
    as_PyntCloud=True)
```

Which looks like this:

[image: thinned cloud]

You can access to the xyz values of the new thinned point cloud as follows:

```
data = thinned_cloud.xyz
```

---

This uses pandas.groupby internally which should be an speed improvement comparing to the code you posted. However if this is still not fast enought I would recommend you to try https://numba.pydata.org/

There are a few example operations wich might be usefull for you in https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/pyntcloud/utils/numba.py

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! I am not familiar with that point cloud package but I will give it a try. The main point of my question was to find out why my python implementation ran slower than the MATLAB one - any lines in my code I could change to speed it up?

Comment: I updated the answer trying to focus on what you should change in the code

Comment: Thanks for the update! I thought about vectorizing the code but didn't find an easier way to implement it.